# Infinispan crashes with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallingConfiguration.setExternalizerCreator

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, infinispan

We have multiple Ubuntu servers, all of them Tomcat 8 and Java 8 update 45; all of them execute our application with no issues; but on a recently created server, the application crashes on initialization with the following (partial) stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.start() on object of type GlobalMarshaller
        at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:241)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:545)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:516)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:398)
        at com.ats.framework.model.dao.impl.SingleTenantInfinispanDirectoryProvider.criaCache(SingleTenantInfinispanDirectoryProvider.java:126)
        at com.ats.framework.model.dao.impl.SingleTenantInfinispanDirectoryProvider.start(SingleTenantInfinispanDirectoryProvider.java:98)
        at com.ats.framework.model.dao.search.impl.MultiTenantDirectoryProvider.getDirectory(MultiTenantDirectoryProvider.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.search.reader.SharingBufferReaderProvider.initialize(SharingBufferReaderProvider.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.search.reader.ReaderProviderFactory.createReaderProvider(ReaderProviderFactory.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.start() on object of type GlobalMarshaller
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:185)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530)
        at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:219)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallingConfiguration.setExternalizerCreator(Lorg/jboss/marshalling/Creator;)V
        at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.<init>(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:64)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller.<init>(JBossMarshaller.java:52)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.start(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:63)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.start(GlobalMarshaller.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:183)
        ... 82 more
```

It's exactly the same JVM as the other servers, exactly the same Tomcat, running exactly the same WAR. Any ideas on what could be causing Infinispan to throw NoSuchMethodError only on an specific server?

Comment: This is really about having incompatible versions on the classpath. What version of `infinispan-core`, `infinispna-commons` and `jboss-marshalling` do you have there?

Comment: Currently, the application is using Infinispan 6.0.2 with jboss-marshalling-1.3.0.CR9. I've also tried version 1.4.4 (that originally came with Infinispan) and 1.4.10, with the same results.

Comment: I've checked jboss-marshalling-osgi-1.4.4.Final.jar and it contains this method. However, it's possible that you have another marshalling jar on the classpath before this one and the correct version is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

While jboss-marshalling/1.4.9.Final and older has the method

```
@Deprecated
public void setExternalizerCreator(final Creator externalizerCreator)
```

The newer version jboss-marshalling/2.0.0.Beta2 does not. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.marshalling/jboss-marshalling/2.0.0.Beta2/org/jboss/marshalling/MarshallingConfiguration.java?av=f). It could be you have a new library that is not compatible with older libs. I would compare the jboss-marshallingXXXXX.jar versions on the old and new servers.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be my case; the application is using Infinispan 6.0.2 with jboss-marshalling-1.3.0.CR9. I've also tried version 1.4.4 (that originally came with Infinispan) and 1.4.10, with the same results.